# What is loaded when using "from foo import *"

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can i list what is imported when calling `"from foo import *"`. I've tried sys.modules.keys() but this one is giving more low-level datatypes.

Comment: Are you looking for a list of the objects and the methods and functions that you can call in foo?

Comment: Lets say i have multiple modules in one directory and i am doing *from mymodules import * i would like to know what actually was loaded

Comment: And now you know why we don't do that.

Comment: It's not about not doing it, i am trying to debug something.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes on the question? Apart from the un-pythonic `from foo import *`, I think it's a valid question.

Answer (score 4):

You should import `foo` without `*`, so you can use `dir` the get all names in `foo`:

```
import foo
print dir(foo)
```

Comment: This outputs only: ['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__'] but i know that there is a module bar shouldn't it be listed here?

Comment: Submodules are not part of the parent module.

Comment: Allright how can i know what submodules are loaded or is part of the partent module?

Comment: @user1767754 Look at my answer below if you're interested in submodules and submodules of submodules of a particular package. `dir` only lists the highest level submodules but doesn't recursively dive into each of them.

Answer (score 2):

As a general Python rule, running `from foo import *` is considered bad style (un-pythonic) as it pollutes the namespace.

I gave your question some thought and here is what I've come up with. Copy/paste the following into iPython using iPython's handy `%paste` magic function, or save it to a script and run it directly:

```
import pkgutil

def list_all_modules(top_level_package):
    modnames = []
    package = top_level_package
    prefix = package.__name__ + "."
    for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(package.__path__, prefix):
        modnames.append(modname)
        if ispkg:
            module = __import__(modname, fromlist="dummy")
            recurse_modnames = list_all_modules(module)
            modnames += recurse_modnames
    return modnames
```

Now you can import your module/library `foo`, pass it to this function, and get back a list (of `str` objects) of all available modules/submodules under package `foo`. Like so:

```
modnames = list_all_modules(foo)
print modnames
```

As a test, I'll run it on the `html5lib` library available [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib).

```
In [2]: from pprint import pprint

In [3]: import html5lib

In [4]: modnames = list_all_modules(html5lib)

In [5]: pprint(modnames)

['html5lib.constants',
 'html5lib.filters',
 'html5lib.filters._base',
 'html5lib.filters.alphabeticalattributes',
 'html5lib.filters.inject_meta_charset',
 'html5lib.filters.lint',
 'html5lib.filters.optionaltags',
 'html5lib.filters.sanitizer',
 'html5lib.filters.whitespace',
 'html5lib.html5parser',
 'html5lib.ihatexml',
 'html5lib.inputstream',
 'html5lib.sanitizer',
 'html5lib.serializer',
 'html5lib.serializer.htmlserializer',
 'html5lib.tokenizer',
 'html5lib.treeadapters',
 'html5lib.treeadapters.sax',
 'html5lib.treebuilders',
 'html5lib.treebuilders._base',
 'html5lib.treebuilders.dom',
 'html5lib.treebuilders.etree',
 'html5lib.treebuilders.etree_lxml',
 'html5lib.treewalkers',
 'html5lib.treewalkers._base',
 'html5lib.treewalkers.dom',
 'html5lib.treewalkers.etree',
 'html5lib.treewalkers.genshistream',
 'html5lib.treewalkers.lxmletree',
 'html5lib.treewalkers.pulldom',
 'html5lib.trie',
 'html5lib.trie._base',
 'html5lib.trie.datrie',
 'html5lib.trie.py',
 'html5lib.utils']
```

This definitely feels like an un-pythonic way to do this, but if anyone has a better way, please let me know. :)